# Sharing log directory from container to Host

Tags: docker

I have an application running in windows ECS containers which generates logs in C:/applogs folder. I want to share this folder (real-time) to thmake host, so that splunk forwarder software can read from the host folder. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

The `Docker` logging mechanism delivers logs from `STDOUT/STDERR` and not from files so you should write your logs to those standard streams rather than a file.
If you are unable to make that change and are logging on files then you can send them to `AWS CloudWatch Logs`, you can mount those locations (eg `C:/applogs folder` in your case) as a volume and configure a CloudWatch logs agent running on the container instances locally to deliver those files.
[OpenTelemetry project](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-collector-contrib/tree/main/exporter/splunkhecexporter) has exporters for sending metrics over to Splunk using a Splunk HTTP Event Collector (HEC) exporter 
The ADOT collector for ECS can be configured with an alternate pipeline configuration using SSM parameter store enabling you to send metrics over to Splunk via the above exporter instead of the default `AWS EMF exporter` to send metrics to Amazon CloudWatch

Reference: [Monitoring your container instances](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/using_cloudwatch_logs.html)
[Use custom OpenTelemetry configuration file from SSM Parameter](https://aws-otel.github.io/docs/setup/ecs/config-through-ssm)